# Is there any way to remove deleted videos all at once from YouTube playlist?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I have several playlists with few hundreds videos each. When any video gets deleted I receive "One or more videos have been removed from the playlist because they were deleted from YouTube" message. Most of the time it is more than one. So, how can I remove all deleted videos? Scrolling down playlist and removing manually takes time.